# What is the correct way to React Hook Fetch Api and store to Redux and retrieve it with Selector immediately?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

This is a React component + custom hook
the goal is to continuously fetching data from external API endpoint every 5 seconds
and I tried to use *`requestAnimationFrame`* instead of *`setInterval`*,

Although it worked (for fetching) but it seems `person.fetchStatus` in *`fetchPerson()`* is not updated accordingly, so it never triggers the safety hatch and break out from it.

I want to know:

1. is this a good practice to write a hook like this?
2. is *`person`* object inside *`fetchPerson()`* memoized and couldn't read the new value from the redux store selector?

*Thanks*

###### Mock Code below

×××××××××××××××××××××××××××××××××××××××

```
function useFetchPerson() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const person = useSelector((state) => state.person)

    const startTimeRef = useRef()
    const idRef = useRef();

    const [chances, setChances] = useState(3)

    const fetchPerson = (timestamp) => {
        const elapse = timestamp - startTimeRef.current; 
        
        // a. run requestAnimationFrame if less than 5 seconds
        if (elapse < 5 * 1000) return idRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(fetchPerson) 

        // b. safty hatch to break from this recursive function
        if (!person.fetchStatus) return setChances(prevChances => --prevChances) ;
        if (chances === 0) return;
        
        // c. go fetch api and save into redux store if 5 sec later and update the startTime 
        dispatch(fetchPersonReduxThunk())
        startTimeRef.current = performance.now();
        idRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(fetchPerson)
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        startTimeRef.current = performance.now();
        idRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(fetchPerson)
        
        return () => cancelAnimationFrame(id)
    },[]);

    return person;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`person` is *sort of memoized* but in the sense that for each time `fetchPerson` is called the value of `person` is closed over in scope. You may want to try saving it to a ref and access the current ref value from within `fetchPerson`.

Several other issues I notice:

1. `setChances(prevChances => --prevChances)` where `--prevChances` would be considered a state mutation and should be avoided, use `setChances(prevChances => prevChances - 1)` instead.
2. I think this may just be a typo, but calling it out just in case. The `useEffect`'s cleanup function appears to reference an undefined `id` variable. `return () => cancelAnimationFrame(id)` I think should be `return () => cancelAnimationFrame(idRef.current)` to clear/cancel the current animation frame.

Code

```
function useFetchPerson() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const personRef = useRef(); // <-- ref to hold person state value
    
  const person = useSelector((state) => state.person);

  useEffect(() => {
    personRef.current = person; // <-- cache person value
  }, [person]);

  const startTimeRef = useRef();
  const idRef = useRef();

  const [chances, setChances] = useState(3);

  const fetchPerson = (timestamp) => {
    const elapse = timestamp - startTimeRef.current; 
        
    // a. run requestAnimationFrame if less than 5 seconds
    if (elapse < 5 * 1000) {
      idRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(fetchPerson);
      return;
    }

    // b. safety hatch to break from this recursive function
    if (!personRef.current?.fetchStatus) { // <-- reference personRef current value
      setChances(chances => chances - 1) ;
      return
    }
    if (chances === 0) return;
        
    // c. go fetch api and save into redux store if 5 sec later and update the startTime 
    dispatch(fetchPersonReduxThunk());
    startTimeRef.current = performance.now();
    idRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(fetchPerson);
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    startTimeRef.current = performance.now();
    idRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(fetchPerson)
        
    return () => cancelAnimationFrame(idRef.current)
  }, []);

  return person;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah q2 is just a typo, and yeah it fixed the problem.
But about the memoized `person`,  why is that happening?   
`person` isn't defined in `fetchPerson()`, so it should go out to `useFetchPerson()` scope to get the `person` latest value from the redux selector, isn't this the right way of thinking?

Comment: @Chapboy If this was pure, synchronous recursion it'd be a non-issue since you'd necessarily hit a base case and "pop" back out of the recursion, all within the bookends of a render cycle, and deal with state that is `const`. But you are running code asynchronously, which allows the `person` state in the redux store to be updated independently of your `fetchPerson` code, and it closes over a copy when it recurses again.